# Getting latest state data in React using useEffect with history.block route guard

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am having issues getting the correct state inside the `history.block` callback, or should I say the `history.block` triggers too early, before the `useEffect` can re-create it with the correct state. Does anyone know what the correct way to setup a route guard would be?

Context is I am updating the status in redux then navigating to a new page. I would like to access that updated status inside of my route guard, but I keep getting one that is one step too old. I'm not sure if this the correct way to do this. I will try to setup a min repro but for now here is the code:

```js
console.log('in the render', status)
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('in the useEffect', status)
  const unlisten = history.block(route => {
    console.log('in the block', status)
    return routeGuard({ status })
  })
  return unlisten
}, [status])
```

Which logs:

```
in the render user-created
in the render user-created
in the render person-created
in the useCallback user-created
in the useCallback user-created
in the useEffect person-created
in the render person-created
```

What I was looking for is `person-created` in the block

How can I change this so I would get the correct status in the `history.block` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by importing the store and calling getState(). This ensures that the state is not stale:

```js
import { store } from '../redux/store'

useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = history.block(route => {
    const status = store.getState().status
    return routeGuard({ status })
  })
  return unlisten
}, [])
```

Comment: From the react-redux documentation: [your own components should never need to care about those details, and won't ever reference the store directly.](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store)

Answer (score 1):

You may have noticed that you have the **previous** value of status in the closure you return as the effect cleanup ([stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)), usually this is what you want in the cleanup because you set up something in the effect for the new value and clean up the old one.

You could create and set a ref to get the current value:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(1);
  const statusRef = React.useRef(status);
  //set the ref on every render
  statusRef.current = status;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("current status:", status);
    return () => {
      console.log("previous status in cleanup:", status);
      console.log(
        "current status in cleanup:",
        statusRef.current
      );
    };
  }, [status]);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setStatus(status + 1)}>
      status: {status}
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```